# Read JSON from URL to display IMG

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a website that analyzes data from a game called Overwatch.

I have this (https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/us/ShalevBito-2753/complete) and when you visit it, all you see is text in JSON format.

Is there anyway I can read this using JavaScript and send the ratingIcon to a nice  tag on my website so I can display it?

Current Code (This is in a < script > tag:

```
let requestUrl = "https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/us/ShalevBito-2753/complete";
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestUrl);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    logData(request.response);
}
function logData(data) {
    document.querySelector('.rating').innerText = `${data['rating']}`;
    document.querySelector('.rank').innerText = `${data['ratingIcon']}`;
}
```

Html:

`<p class="rating"</p>
<img class="rank"</img>`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but your HTML in your question is incorrect. You haven't closed your opening tags. Should be `<p class="rating"></p>` and `img` doesn't need a closing tag so it should be `<img class="rank" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change the `src` attribute of your `img`

```
document.querySelector('.rank').src = `${data['ratingIcon']}`;
```

And fix your `img` tag:

```
<img class="rank" />
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dxx0y2dh/

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You have a problem in your HTML, it should be:

```
<p class="rating"></p>
<img class="rank"/>
```

Also, you should change the `src` attribute instead of the `innerHTML` property for the image to render, like this:

```
document.querySelector('.rank').src = `${data['ratingIcon']}`;
```

Here you have a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mzzrx40h/

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you should probably mark @ChinLeung answer as accepted, it was posted 21 seconds before mine hehe

Answer (score 0):

... you already were pretty close. You just need to use the right syntax when assigning the correct data properties to the correct element properties.

```js
let requestUrl = "https://ow-api.com/v1/stats/pc/us/ShalevBito-2753/complete";
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestUrl);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    logData(request.response);
}
function logData(data) {
    document.querySelector('.rating').innerText = data.rating;
    document.querySelector('.rank').src = data.ratingIcon;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<p class="rating"></p>
<img class="rank"/>
```